# AS3 Errors 1180 and 1046

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, import, compiler-errors

I am new to AS3 and still trying to understand it. I am trying to import a class from a different .as file in my main .fla file. I know that the errors are the result of me trying to reference a class that the .fla file doesn't have.

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Code', Frame 1, Line 6  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method bg.
Scene 1, Layer 'Code', Frame 1, Line 6  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: bg.
Scene 1, Layer 'Code', Frame 1, Line 4  1172: Definition thebackground:bg could not be found.
Scene 1, Layer 'Code', Frame 1, Line 4  1172: Definition thebackground:bg could not be found.
```

it probably has something to do with me importing incorrectly, but what that mistake may be I can't say I have any idea. I added a constructor to instantiate bg (at least I think I did.) Will continue to scout for more info, but everything I've found hasn't been anything that I can gather a working result from.
with that said, here is what I have thus far:

```
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import thebackground.bg;

var testbg:bg = new bg;
var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var downPressed:Boolean = false;

testbg.moveBackGround();
```

This is what I have in my main .fla file at present.

```
package thebackground
{
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class bg extends MovieClip
{

    var xScrollSpeed:int = 10;
    var yScrollSpeed:int = 10;

public function moveBackGround(event:Event):void
{
    if(leftPressed)
    {
        BG.x += xScrollSpeed;
    }
    else if(rightPressed)
    {
        BG.x -= xScrollSpeed;
    }
    else if(upPressed)
    {
        BG.y += yScrollSpeed;
    }
    else if(downPressed)
    {
        BG.y -= yScrollSpeed;
    }
}
}
}
```

and this is what is in thebackground.as

Comment: Your bg class has no constructor. You need something like `public function bg():void`

Comment: this is just the first error, `testbg.moveBackGround()` will also throw an error as `moveBackGround(e)` needs an Event as a parameter; also bg will not access vars in your main file (ie. `upPressed`)